# typedef struct and char in C programming

Tags: c, char, typedef

I find myself stuck for a few minutes on a piece of code that does not work as I wish. Indeed I would like to insert a character into a structure that contains an array of characters.

Here's an excerpt from the code snippet "automates.h":

```
void ajouterCaractere(Automate *automate) {
    if(automate->nbre_caracteres >= MAX_CARACTERES){
        printf("Vous avez deja atteint le nombre de caracteres maximal pour l'alphabet de votre automate !\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Veuillez inserer un caractere dans alphabet :\n");
        scanf("%c",&automate->alphabet[automate->nbre_caracteres]);
        automate->nbre_caracteres++;
    }
}

// Remplir les états
void ajouterEtat(Automate *automate) {
    if (automate->nbre_etats >= MAX_ETATS) {
        printf("Vous avez deja atteint le nombre d'etats maximal pour votre automate !\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Veuillez inserer un etat de votre automate :\n");
        scanf("%d", &automate->tableau_Etat[automate->nbre_etats]);
        automate->nbre_etats++;
    }
}

// Remplir les états initiaux
void ajouterEtatInitial(Automate *automate) {
    if (automate->nbre_etats_initiaux >= MAX_ETATS_INITIAUX) {
        printf("Vous avez deja atteint le nombre d'etats initiaux maximal pour votre automate !\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Veuillez inserer les etats initiaux de votre automate :\n");
        scanf("%d",&automate->tableau_EI[automate->nbre_etats_initiaux]);
        automate->nbre_etats_initiaux++;
    }
}

// Remplir les états finaux
void ajouterEtatFinal(Automate *automate) {
    if (automate->nbre_etats_finaux >= MAX_ETATS_FINAUX) {
        printf("Vous avez deja atteint le nombre d'etats finaux maximal pour votre automate !\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Veuillez inserer les etats finaux de votre automate :\n");
        scanf("%d",&automate->tableau_EF[automate->nbre_etats_finaux]);
        automate->nbre_etats_finaux++;
    }
}

// Remplir les transitions
void ajouterTransition(Automate *automate) {
    Transition transition;
    int i;

    if (automate->nbre_transitions >= MAX_TRANSITIONS) {
        printf("Vous avez deja atteint le nombre de transition maximal pour votre automate !\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Transition %d\n", automate->nbre_transitions+1);
        printf("\t Etat de depart :   ");           /* L'état de départ de la transition */
        scanf("%d", &transition.etat_depart);
        printf("\t Etiquette :   ");                /* L'étiquette de la transition */
        scanf("%c", &transition.etiquette);         
        printf("\t Etat d'arrive :   ");            /* L'état d'arrivé de la transition */
        scanf("%d", &transition.etat_final);

        automate->tableau_transition[automate->nbre_transitions] = transition;
        automate->nbre_transitions++;
    }
}
```

Here's my main.c :

```
Automate *automate;
    int choix;

    automate = (Automate *) malloc (sizeof(Automate));
    if (automate == NULL)
        printf("Erreur lors de l'allocation de la mémoire à l'automate !\n");

    initialisation(automate);
    //consigne();
    while(choix != 6) {
        choix = menu(automate);
        switch(choix) {
            case 1:
                ajouterCaractere(automate);
                break;
            case 2:
                ajouterEtat(automate);
                break;
            case 3:
                ajouterEtatInitial(automate);
                break;
            case 4:
                ajouterEtatFinal(automate);
                break;
            case 5:
                ajouterTransition(automate);
                break;
            default :
                printf("Faites un choix correcte !");
                break;
        }
    }
```

When i compile i get this :

```
******** MENU ********
1.  Ajouter un caractere dans l'alphabet
2.  Quitter !
Faites votre choix :   
1
Veuillez inserer un caractere dans alphabet :

******** MENU ********
1.  Ajouter un caractere
2.  Ajouter un etat
3.  Ajouter un etat initial
4.  Ajouter un etat final
5.  Ajouter une transition
6.  Quitter
Faites votre choix :
```

As you can see, when I type 1, it does not allow to insert a character in the table.

How to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: There is incomplete code, when a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is usual. Minor: `int choix` is uninitialsed, so a better loop might be `while((choix = menu(automate)) != 6) { switch /* etc */ }`

Comment: Header files are for 1) function signatures 2) data definitions 3) macros  NOT for source code.  The source code should be in a separate .C file,  Compile both .C files, then link them together.  Both .C files should `#include` the header file.

Answer (score 1):

The `menu()` function probably isn't reading the newline after the menu selection. Either fix that function, or change your `scanf()` format string to skip over whitespace before the character.

```
        scanf(" %c",&automate->alphabet[automate->nbre_caracteres]);
```

You should do the same thing for all the other `scanf()` operations that use `%c`.

A better option may be to use `fgets()` to read whole lines into strings, rather than using `scanf()` to read user input. You can use `sscanf()` to parse the input lines.

Comment: Also: `scanf("%c", &transition.etiquette);`